# fitvids loads in development but does not precompile on heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using the jquery.fitvids plugin.  My application.js includes

```
//= require jquery-placeholder
//= require fitvids
//= require flexslider
//= require js-cookie
```

I am using `bower-rails` to manage the jquery plugins so the `jquery.fitvids.js` is stored under `vendor/assets/bower_components/fitvids`.  In development, fitvids loads and works. When I try to push to heroku, I get the following error:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'fitvids'
remote:        (in /tmp/build_d90a6809ebf196379ed83d88b9390b57/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:8)
remote:        /tmp/build_d90a6809ebf196379ed83d88b9390b57/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:106:in `resolve'
```

If I take the `require fitvids` directive out of `application.js` then the assets do pre-compilel despite `jquery.flexslider.js` being similarly located under `vendor/assets/bower_components/flexslider`. The only substantive difference I can see is that there is also an additional minified version of flexslider but not fitvids.

Why isnt the precompile working in production for fitvids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that when I originally installed fitvids using bower-rails, I used the github repository name of FitVids, so bower-rails created a directory of that name. Later, when I altered the name to fitvids (all lower case), then github did not fully register the change. This is a known feature of gibhub, related to it needing to work between file systems that recognise capitalisation and those that do not.  As a result, the capitalised version of the directory, which was empty, was deploying to Heroku.

The solution was to complete remove the fitvids folder from the disk and git, and then do a fresh re-install.  Thanks to SergeyKishenin at bower-rails for assisting with this.