# Which version of the Bower package name should be used when installing with bower-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

Some package names, e.g. FitVids use camelcased spelling for their github repository, yet when you search the Bower repository for them, e.g  http://bower.io/search/?q=FitVids, it returns an all lower case name.

It has been my experience that if you install with the wrong name, you can end up with subtle bugs, e.g. [fitvids loads in development but does not precompile on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938962/fitvids-loads-in-development-but-does-not-precompile-on-heroku)

Which name should I use when installing with bower-rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that correct way is to use the registered name for a component, lower cased for FitVids example. Also, see the related [thread](https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails/issues/161) on Github